# How to prevent a user from entering duplicate email?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use [jQuery Plugin For Email Address Management - Multiple Emails](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/email-multiple.html)

I want to prevent the user from entering two identical emails.
To do this, I use the array. Every email that is entered is poured into the array.
In fact, my goal is to prevent the user from entering duplicate emails
But unfortunately I can not do it properly

```
 var items = [];
    function guardarNumeros() {
        boxvalue = $('.email-ids').text();
        items.push(boxvalue);
        console.log(items);
        // Check if a value exists in the fruits array
        if (items.indexOf("a@a.com") !== -1) {
            console.log("Value exists!")
        } else {
            console.log("Value does not exists!")
        }
    } 




return this.each(function () {
        $(this).after("<span class=\"to-input\">Email :</span>\n" +
            "<div class=\"all-mail\"></div>\n" +
            "<input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" class=\"enter-mail-id\" placeholder=\"Enter Email ...\" />");
        let $orig = $(this);
        let $element = $('.enter-mail-id');
        $element.keydown(function (e) {
            var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            $element.css('border', '');
            if (keycode == "13" || keycode == "188" || keycode == "9" || keycode == "32") {
                let getValue = $element.val();

                if (/^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/.test(getValue)) {
                    $('.all-mail').append(
                        '<span class="email-ids">' + getValue + 
                        '<span class="cancel-email">x</span></span>' );
                    $element.val('');
                    email += getValue + ';'
                    guardarNumeros()
                } else {
                    $element.css('border', '1px solid red')
                }
            }

            $orig.val(email.slice(0, -1))
        });
```

[image]

Can you help me
Thank

Answer (score 1):

you always are checking if the "a@a.com" was entered.
try something like:

```
if (items.indexOf( boxvalue ) !== -1) {
   console.log("Value exists!")
} else {
   console.log("Value does not exists!")
   items.push(boxvalue);  
}
```